# Javascript - What does (1, 2) actually mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I know that in javascript the syntax `(1, 'a', 5, ... 'b')` will always return the last value but what does this syntax actually mean? When I see `(1, 2)` -- which, admittedly is pretty much never -- how should I parse that syntax?

Comment: ... Actual arguments being passed to a method/function? (Are you confusing this with boolean expressions like `1 && 'a' && 5 && ... 'b'`?)

Comment: Mozilla documentation for the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: @Snowball: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @EthanB - nope. Try it in the console, it works. Surprised the crap out of me the first time too :)

Comment: Wow. I just learned something new....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which evaluates two expression and returns the second one.  Since it evaluates arguments from left to right, if you have a list of arguments separated by commas the last one will be returned.  From [The Elements of JavaScript Style](http://javascript.crockford.com/style1.html):

> The comma operator was borrowed, like much of JavaScript's syntax, from C. The comma operator takes two values and returns the second one. Its presence in the language definition tends to mask certain coding errors, so compilers tend to be blind to some mistakes. It is best to avoid the comma operator, and use the semicolon statement separator instead.

Comment: Aww, borrowed from C? I was hoping this was one of the scheme ***should use*** influences. Back to the bottom of the closet comma operator.

Answer (score 5):

The individual expressions - the bits between the commas - are evaluated, then the overall expression takes the value of the last one. So listing a series of numeric and string literals like your example is kind of pointless:

```
(1, 'a', 5, ... 'b')
// does the same thing as
('b')
```

...so you might as well leave out all but the last. However if the individual expressions have other effects because they are function calls or assignments then you can't leave them out.

About the only good reason I can think of to use this syntax is within a `for` statement, because `for` syntax:

```
for([init]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

...doesn't allow you to use semicolons within the `[init]` part, or within the `[condition]` or `[final-expression]` parts. But you *can* include multiple expressions using commas:

```
for(x = 0, y = 100, z = 1000; x < y; x++, y--, z-=100) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `,` operator evaluates both its arguments and returns the last one.

It is most commonly used in `for` loops:

```
for( i=0, j=0; ...)
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator evaluates each item, then returns the last one:

```
var x = (1, 2, 3);
console.log(x == 3);  // true
```

Here's [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses - is just a priority changing operator. So in this case you may omit them.

And you leave with `1, 2`, which is just two expressions separated by comma.

Comment: This is incorrect. The comma can be an operator in JS. aka `var a = (1,2);` is different that `var a = 1,2;`

Comment: @BLSully: it is only different because of [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) (assignment is higher than comma). That is what parentheses there are used for. So your note is not entirely valid.

Comment: Ok, if you ignore the "in this case you may omit them". We do not have context of the OP's program. If he's looking at someone else's code `var x = 10; var a = (3, x);` and tell him he can change that to `var x = 10; var a = 3, x;` it will change the output of following code that uses `a` (Regardless of how contrived that example is...)

Comment: @BLSully: I've explained that: a) Parentheses is not a part of a comma-operator-related syntax, it is only for changing precedence. And for nothing else. As long as `,` has the lowest precedence - parentheses are always used there, **BUT** my aim was to focus that parentheses is *another language construction*, that is used *when necessary* b) If we only talk about `(a, b)` expression we can omit parentheses, because, as I said, it is only for precedence and isn't required from syntax point of view.